Fixing error in resolving dependencies in nestjs
I have a few services (modules) that reference each other. I am now trying to get one of my services to call a function inside another service. I tried updating the constructor to include the service but whenever I run the application I get the following error
[Backend] info  2024-10-22 02:56:56.900 [NestFactory]   Starting Nest application...
[Backend] info  2024-10-22 02:56:56.909 [InjectorLogger]        Nest encountered an undefined dependency. This may be due to a circular import or a missing dependency declaration.
[Backend] info  2024-10-22 02:56:56.910 [InjectorLogger]        Nest encountered an undefined dependency. This may be due to a circular import or a missing dependency declaration.
[Backend] error 2024-10-22 02:56:56.915 [ExceptionHandler]      Nest can't resolve dependencies of the FileParseValidateService (PrismaService, ?, +). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [1] is available in the FileParseValidateModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is FileParseValidateModule a valid NestJS module?
- If dependency is a provider, is it part of the current FileParseValidateModule?
- If dependency is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within FileParseValidateModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing dependency */ ]
  })

Here are all of my services and their modules:
file_submission.service.ts
constructor(
    private prisma: PrismaService,
    private readonly objectStore: ObjectStoreService,
    private readonly aqiService: AqiApiService,

  ) {}

file_submission.module.ts
@Module({
  controllers: [FileSubmissionsController],
  providers: [FileSubmissionsService, SanitizeService],
  exports: [FileSubmissionsService],
  imports: [ObjectStoreModule, AqiApiModule],
})
export class FileSubmissionsModule {}

cron-job.service.ts
constructor(
    private prisma: PrismaService,
    private readonly fileParser: FileParseValidateService,
    private readonly objectStore: ObjectStoreService,
  ) {}

cron-job.module.ts
@Module({
  providers: [CronJobService],
  exports: [CronJobService],
  imports: [FileParseValidateModule, ObjectStoreModule],
})
export class CronJobModule {}

file_parseand_validation.service.ts
constructor(
    private prisma: PrismaService,
    private readonly fileSubmissionsService: FileSubmissionsService,
    private readonly aqiService: AqiApiService,
  ) {}

file_parse_and_validation.module.ts
@Module({
  providers: [FileParseValidateService, ],
  exports: [FileParseValidateService],
  imports: [HttpModule, FileSubmissionsModule, ObjectStoreModule, AqiApiModule]
})
export class FileParseValidateModule {}

aqi_api.service.ts
constructor(
    private cronJobService: CronJobService,
    private prisma: PrismaService,
  ) {}

aqi_api.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  providers: [AqiApiService],
  exports: [AqiApiService],
})
export class AqiApiModule {}

The application will start and work as expected if I remove private cronJobService: CronJobService from the aqi_api.service.ts constructor. As soon as I add that in order to use a function inside my cronJobService I get the error mentioned above. I tried using madge (npx madge . -c) to find any circular dependencies and I get the following message
1) dist/aqi_api/aqi_api.service.js > dist/cron-job/cron-job.service.js > dist/file_parse_and_validation/file_parse_and_validation.service.js
2) dist/aqi_api/aqi_api.service.js > dist/cron-job/cron-job.service.js > dist/file_parse_and_validation/file_parse_and_validation.service.js > dist/file_submissions/file_submissions.service.js

I've tried all the options from the Official Documentation. docs NestJs circular-dependency
Thanks, best regards
